# Custom bindings are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a textarea element with this specific attributes for style property        ->overflow:hidden;resize:none and height:20px. In this case when I have a long text on multiple lines my textarea will display only the first row. The idea is that I want to make it to resize when I click on it, in such a manner that the whole text is visible.I am using Knockout JS and I cannot realise what is wrong with my bindings.

```js
function TextAreaVM() {
    this.active = ko.observable(false);
    
    this.text = ko.observable("Something\nnew line\nanother new line");

    this.setActive = function(){
        this.active(true);
    };

    this.notActive = function(){
        this.active(false);
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.maximize ={
        update: function(element,valueAccessor){
            element.style.height = element.style.scroolHeight + "px";
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.minimize={
        update: function(element,valueAccessor){
            element.style.height = "20px";
        }
    };

}

ko.applyBindings(new TextAreaVM());
```

```css
#txtarea-id{
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txtarea-id" class="txtarea-class" height="20px" 
            data-bind="text: text, 
            event: {focus: setActive, blur: notActive},
            maximize: (active() == true),
            minimize: (active() == false)"
            readonly="true"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtarea-second" class="txtarea-class" height="20px" 
            width="50px" readonly="true">This is the first line and it should appear only on the first row&#13;&#10;This line shuld appera only o the second row!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried `element.style.scroolHeight.toString()` and things like `data-bind="maximize: active(), minimize: !active()"` but none of them works. Also I am 100% sure that my boolean "active" works properly (I tried to debug using Chrome and it behaves how I want->When I click on a textarea it is true and when I click outside it is false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just three minor issues with the code:

1. In your question you have two bindings named `maximize`. Rename one of them to `minimize` to avoid conflict.
2. In the binding handlers, you are not validating against the value of `valueAccessor` before setting element's height. As a result, everytime `active` observable changes, both binding handlers are triggered. So the handler called last will override the result of the previous one. So you would never see the height changing.
3. You have a typo in `scroolHeight`. It should be `element.scrollHeight`.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.maximize = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    if(valueAccessor()) {
     element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.minimize = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    if(valueAccessor()) {
      element.style.height = "20px";
    }
  }
};

function TextAreaVM() {
  this.active = ko.observable(false);

  this.text = ko.observable("Something\nnew line\nanother new line");

  this.setActive = function() {
    this.active(true);
  };

  this.notActive = function() {
    this.active(false);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new TextAreaVM());
```

```css
#txtarea-id {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="txtarea-id" class="txtarea-class" height="20px" data-bind="text: text, 
            event: {focus: setActive, blur: notActive},
            maximize: (active() == true),
            minimize: (active() == false)" readonly="true"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

### Update

When you are using single binding for multiple elements, you'd have to validate that the element is the one which has focus. So adding `element === document.activeElement` to the `if` condition should be sufficient. I have updated the snippet with minor changes to your code (as posted in comments) to show how it would work.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.resize = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    if (valueAccessor() && element === document.activeElement) {
      element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
    } else {
      element.style.height = "20px";
    }
  }
};

function TextAreaVM() {
  this.active = ko.observable(false);

  this.text = ko.observable("Something\nnew line\nanother new line");

  this.setActive = function() {
    this.active(true);
  };

  this.notActive = function() {
    this.active(false);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new TextAreaVM());
```

```css
.txtarea-class {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="txtarea-id" class="txtarea-class" height="20px" data-bind="text: text, 
            event: {focus: setActive, blur: notActive},
            resize: active()" readonly="true"></textarea>
            

  <br/>
  <textarea id="txtarea-id2" class="txtarea-class" height="20px" data-bind="text: text, 
            event: {focus: setActive, blur: notActive},
            resize: active()" readonly="true"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One more question: If i want to use just one binding like this: data-bind="text: text, 
            event: {focus: setActive, blur: notActive}, resize: (active() == true || active() == false)" and in my view-model I have sth like this : ko.bindingHandlers.resize = {
            update: function(element,valueAccessor){
                if(active() == true) {
                    element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
                else{
                    element.style.height = "20px";
                }
            }
        };

Comment: and i have more instances of the textarea it selects all of them and apply the height of the seleced one to all. What should I do in order to apply the desired height only to the selected one.Thank you!

Comment: @BogdanV It should work fine with some changes. I've updated my answer to show how that would work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.It worked and I really appreciate your help.Do you know,is there any way to customize the textarea so it doesn't add a new line when the text exceeds the maximum width, so it is in a situation of overflow-x and I can see the whole text with a scroll on x.Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that. You should probably post a new question.

Comment: I edited the original code and I added a second textarea with two lines but because of the small width it displays the first line of text on multiple rows. I want it to display only as much as it can and the rest of the text to be outside(overflow-x situation) and be able to scroll in order to reach that part of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at knockout, but you are defining twice:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.maximize ={
    update: function(element,valueAccessor){
        element.style.height = "20px";
    }
};
```

Meaning only the last will be taken into account (and this one is the last one).

Comment: Ooops .I'm sorry but it was a mistake.I edited the code in order to look exactly just as the original one.